# python3 breaks apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, python3

I'm trying to upgrade my system but python3 is breaking the process:

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.5.1-3) but 3.5.1-4 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.5.1-3) but 3.5.1-4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

so I rerun with -f and got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3 python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
441 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 134 kB/143 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk all 1:16.10.7 [9,292 B]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:16.10.7 [21.2 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:16.10.7 [103 kB]
Fetched 134 kB in 0s (586 kB/s)                         
Setting up python3-minimal (3.5.1-4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 290, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 262, in main
    options.optimize, e_patterns)
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 156, in compile
    cfn = interpreter.cache_file(fn, version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 212, in cache_file
    (fname[:-3], self.magic_tag(version), last_char))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 246, in magic_tag
    return self._execute('import imp; print(imp.get_tag())', version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 359, in _execute
    raise Exception('{} failed with status code {}'.format(command, output['returncode']))
Exception: python3.5 -c 'import imp; print(imp.get_tag())' failed with status code 1
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

if I do sudo apt -f install I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
441 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,710 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-minimal (3.5.1-4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 290, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 262, in main
    options.optimize, e_patterns)
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 156, in compile
    cfn = interpreter.cache_file(fn, version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 212, in cache_file
    (fname[:-3], self.magic_tag(version), last_char))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 246, in magic_tag
    return self._execute('import imp; print(imp.get_tag())', version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 359, in _execute
    raise Exception('{} failed with status code {}'.format(command, output['returncode']))
Exception: python3.5 -c 'import imp; print(imp.get_tag())' failed with status code 1
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you uninstall python2 which is the default python. Or just change default? Either way you broke system, it still depends on python2. They have planned for years totally convert to python3, but several applications are not yet ready. You must maintain default python as link to python2.

Comment: I still have python2.7.12

Comment: But apt should not be using python3, did you then change default? Post this, default install will say python2.7v `ls -l /usr/bin/python` and/or: `python --version` More info: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110364

Comment: both commands says python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt purge -f python3` fixed the problem, and the system still has python 2.7 and 3.5